# How to make Visual Studio web app project that compiles nothing, yet still starts IIS Express and the debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, vs-web-application-project

I want to make an MSBuild script that:

- can be "built" or "rebuilt" or "cleaned" or "started" by Visual Studio like a normal project
- doesn't actually compile anything
- runs some custom tasks (arbitrary to the question)
- supports Visual Studio firing up IIS Express and the debugger when "started"

I can create a nearly empty web application project and add pre/post-build tasks.  However, I'd like to skip the unnecessary compilation steps altogether.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you modify the BuildDependsOn property to exclude the "CoreBuild" target? Take an approach similar to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/02/10/528822.aspx) but delete the "CoreBuild" target rather than adding an extra one?

Comment: Excellent! I added this line to my project file, and it seems to work:

    `<Target Name="CoreBuild" />`

Building the project still creates /bin, /obj, and some files in /obj.  I wonder how I can skip that.